Why does one of my LED lights come on late and dim?
I installed 15 or so Sylvania canless LED “micro disk” lights last spring.  2 of them started having issues with brightness. 1 of the lights is in a gang of 4 on its own single pole dimmer switch.  The other is 1 of 2 lights in a 3 pole switch.  The light on the 3 pole was replaced, and issue seems solved.  However the light in the group of 4 is still having issues after replacement.
The issue originated in the 2nd light in the line. 1 of the 4 lights turns on with a short delay and is at about 10% brightness when the other 3 are at 100%.  That was resolved after replacement. Now issue is in 3rd light line.  (3rd light never had issues at the same time as the 2nd in line). 1st and 4th lights have had no issue.
So far I have done the following:

Replaced light as described above. Issue moved to 3rd light.
Adjusted the dimmer intensity as indicated on the spec sheet.  No resolution.
Removed dimmer switch and replaced with a non dimming single pole switch.  No resolution.

Note- the light comes on dimly about 1 second after the other 3. Problem light then intermittently gets bright, then dim. Not flashing, but stays bright or dim for 10-20 seconds.
What am I missing - any suggestions?!
Tia!
